# STM32F411, FreeRTOS and CubeMX HardFault_Handler() after connecting to port

Tags: freertos, stm32f4, cubemx, truestudio

I need help with my project. I'm using Atollic TrueSTUDIO, CubeMX and FreeRTOS. I have project in which I recived data from ADC and I'm trying to send it by USB. Everything works fine until I open port at PC (I'm trying HTerm, RealTerm, etc), after that dubugging stops and `HardFault_Handler()` appears.

Here is my main.c (everything is generate by CubeMX for FreeRTOS:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "usb_device.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
#include "time.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0;
osThreadId defaultTaskHandle;
osThreadId sendTaskHandle;
osThreadId recivedTaskHandle;
osThreadId prepareTaskHandle;
osSemaphoreId myBinarySem01Handle;
osSemaphoreId myBinarySem02Handle;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
#define length 2048
uint16_t preparedData[(length/8)];
uint8_t dataToSend[(length/16)];
uint16_t recivedData[(length/2)];
uint8_t sendCounter = 0;
clock_t start, end;
int cpu_time_used = 0;
SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphore = NULL;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument);
void StartSendTask(void const * argument);
void StartADCTask(void const * argument);
void StartPrepareTask(void const * argument);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* Create the semaphores(s) */
  /* definition and creation of myBinarySem01 */
  osSemaphoreDef(myBinarySem01);
  myBinarySem01Handle = osSemaphoreCreate(osSemaphore(myBinarySem01), 1);
  /* definition and creation of myBinarySem02 */
  osSemaphoreDef(myBinarySem02);
  myBinarySem02Handle = osSemaphoreCreate(osSemaphore(myBinarySem02), 1);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* definition and creation of defaultTask */
  osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
  defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of sendTask */
  osThreadDef(sendTask, StartSendTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 512);
  sendTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(sendTask), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of recivedTask */
  osThreadDef(recivedTask, StartADCTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 1024);
  recivedTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(recivedTask), NULL);

  /* definition and creation of prepareTask */
  osThreadDef(prepareTask, StartPrepareTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 1024);
  prepareTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(prepareTask), NULL);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */


  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 72;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15, 0);
}

/* ADC1 init function */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 4;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_10;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_11;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_12;
  sConfig.Rank = 3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_13;
  sConfig.Rank = 4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  * Configure DMA for memory to memory transfers
  *   hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* Configure DMA request hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0 on DMA2_Stream0 */
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Instance = DMA2_Stream0;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_MEMORY;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_ENABLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_SINGLE;
  hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_SINGLE;
  if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_memtomem_dma2_stream0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream4_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream4_IRQn);

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartDefaultTask */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the defaultTask thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used 
  * @retval None
  */

/* USER CODE END Header_StartDefaultTask */
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* init code for USB_DEVICE */
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
    {
//        vTaskResume( sendTaskHandle );
//        vTaskResume( prepareTaskHandle );
//        vTaskResume( recivedTaskHandle );
//        vTaskSuspend( defaultTaskHandle );
    }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartSendTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the sendTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/

/* USER CODE END Header_StartSendTask */
void StartSendTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartSendTask */
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem01Handle, ( TickType_t ) 100 ) )
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
          volatile uint8_t send = CDC_Transmit_FS( dataToSend, (length/16) );
          if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle ) == pdTRUE )
          {
              taskYIELD();
          }
      } else {
          taskYIELD();
      }

  }
  /* USER CODE END StartSendTask */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartADCTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the recivedTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/

/* USER CODE END Header_StartADCTask */
void StartADCTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartADCTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem01Handle, ( TickType_t ) 100 ) )
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
          for( int i = 0 ; i < (length/8) ; i++ ){
              HAL_ADC_Start_DMA( &hadc1, recivedData, (length/2));
          }
          if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle ) == pdTRUE )
          {
              taskYIELD();
          }
      } else {
          taskYIELD();
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartADCTask */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartPrepareTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the prepareTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/

/* USER CODE END Header_StartPrepareTask */
void StartPrepareTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartPrepareTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem01Handle, ( TickType_t ) 100 ) )
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
          volatile uint8_t counter = 0;
          for( int i = 0; i < (length / ( 2 * 16 * 4)); i ++){
              for( int j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                  preparedData[counter] += recivedData[i * 16 + j * 4];
                  preparedData[counter + 1] += recivedData[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 1];
                  preparedData[counter + 2] += recivedData[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 2];
                  preparedData[counter + 3] += recivedData[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 3];
              }
              counter += 4;
          }
          for( int i = 0; i < (length / 16); i += 2){
              dataToSend[0 + i] = preparedData[i / 2] >> 8;
              dataToSend[1 + i] = (preparedData[i / 2] << 8) >> 8;
          }
          if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle ) == pdTRUE )
          {
              taskYIELD();
          }
      } else {
          taskYIELD();
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartPrepareTask */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Here is my usbd_cdc_if.c:

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN INCLUDE */

/* USER CODE END INCLUDE */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/** @addtogroup STM32_USB_OTG_DEVICE_LIBRARY
  * @brief Usb device library.
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup USBD_CDC_IF
  * @{
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Private_TypesDefinitions USBD_CDC_IF_Private_TypesDefinitions
  * @brief Private types.
  * @{
  */

/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_TYPES */

/* USER CODE END PRIVATE_TYPES */

/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Defines USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Defines
  * @brief Private defines.
  * @{
  */

/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_DEFINES */
/* Define size for the receive and transmit buffer over CDC */
/* It's up to user to redefine and/or remove those define */
#define APP_RX_DATA_SIZE 128
#define APP_TX_DATA_SIZE 128
/* USER CODE END PRIVATE_DEFINES */

/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Macros USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Macros
  * @brief Private macros.
  * @{
  */

/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_MACRO */

/* USER CODE END PRIVATE_MACRO */

/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Variables USBD_CDC_IF_Private_Variables
  * @brief Private variables.
  * @{
  */
/* Create buffer for reception and transmission           */
/* It's up to user to redefine and/or remove those define */
/** Received data over USB are stored in this buffer      */
uint8_t UserRxBufferFS[APP_RX_DATA_SIZE];

/** Data to send over USB CDC are stored in this buffer   */
uint8_t UserTxBufferFS[APP_TX_DATA_SIZE];

/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_VARIABLES */

/* USER CODE END PRIVATE_VARIABLES */

/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Exported_Variables USBD_CDC_IF_Exported_Variables
  * @brief Public variables.
  * @{
  */

extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;

/* USER CODE BEGIN EXPORTED_VARIABLES */

/* USER CODE END EXPORTED_VARIABLES */

/**
  * @}
  */

/** @defgroup USBD_CDC_IF_Private_FunctionPrototypes USBD_CDC_IF_Private_FunctionPrototypes
  * @brief Private functions declaration.
  * @{
  */

static int8_t CDC_Init_FS(void);
static int8_t CDC_DeInit_FS(void);
static int8_t CDC_Control_FS(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t* pbuf, uint16_t length);
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* pbuf, uint32_t *Len);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PRIVATE_FUNCTIONS_DECLARATION */

/* USER CODE END PRIVATE_FUNCTIONS_DECLARATION */

/**
  * @}
  */

USBD_CDC_ItfTypeDef USBD_Interface_fops_FS =
{
  CDC_Init_FS,
  CDC_DeInit_FS,
  CDC_Control_FS,
  CDC_Receive_FS
};

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
  * @brief  Initializes the CDC media low layer over the FS USB IP
  * @retval USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL
  */
static int8_t CDC_Init_FS(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  /* Set Application Buffers */
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, UserTxBufferFS, 0);
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, UserRxBufferFS);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief  DeInitializes the CDC media low layer
  * @retval USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL
  */
static int8_t CDC_DeInit_FS(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 4 */
}

/**
  * @brief  Manage the CDC class requests
  * @param  cmd: Command code
  * @param  pbuf: Buffer containing command data (request parameters)
  * @param  length: Number of data to be sent (in bytes)
  * @retval Result of the operation: USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL
  */
static int8_t CDC_Control_FS(uint8_t cmd, uint8_t* pbuf, uint16_t length)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  switch(cmd)
  {
    case CDC_SEND_ENCAPSULATED_COMMAND:

    break;

    case CDC_GET_ENCAPSULATED_RESPONSE:

    break;

    case CDC_SET_COMM_FEATURE:

    break;

    case CDC_GET_COMM_FEATURE:

    break;

    case CDC_CLEAR_COMM_FEATURE:

    break;

  /*******************************************************************************/
  /* Line Coding Structure                                                       */
  /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Offset | Field       | Size | Value  | Description                          */
  /* 0      | dwDTERate   |   4  | Number |Data terminal rate, in bits per second*/
  /* 4      | bCharFormat |   1  | Number | Stop bits                            */
  /*                                        0 - 1 Stop bit                       */
  /*                                        1 - 1.5 Stop bits                    */
  /*                                        2 - 2 Stop bits                      */
  /* 5      | bParityType |  1   | Number | Parity                               */
  /*                                        0 - None                             */
  /*                                        1 - Odd                              */
  /*                                        2 - Even                             */
  /*                                        3 - Mark                             */
  /*                                        4 - Space                            */
  /* 6      | bDataBits  |   1   | Number Data bits (5, 6, 7, 8 or 16).          */
  /*******************************************************************************/
    case CDC_SET_LINE_CODING:

    break;

    case CDC_GET_LINE_CODING:

    break;

    case CDC_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE:

    break;

    case CDC_SEND_BREAK:

    break;

  default:
    break;
  }

  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/**
  * @brief  Data received over USB OUT endpoint are sent over CDC interface
  *         through this function.
  *
  *         @note
  *         This function will block any OUT packet reception on USB endpoint
  *         untill exiting this function. If you exit this function before transfer
  *         is complete on CDC interface (ie. using DMA controller) it will result
  *         in receiving more data while previous ones are still not sent.
  *
  * @param  Buf: Buffer of data to be received
  * @param  Len: Number of data received (in bytes)
  * @retval Result of the operation: USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL
  */
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}

/**
  * @brief  CDC_Transmit_FS
  *         Data to send over USB IN endpoint are sent over CDC interface
  *         through this function.
  *         @note
  *
  *
  * @param  Buf: Buffer of data to be sent
  * @param  Len: Number of data to be sent (in bytes)
  * @retval USBD_OK if all operations are OK else USBD_FAIL or USBD_BUSY
  */
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
  if (hcdc->TxState != 0){
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  /* USER CODE END 7 */
  return result;
}
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself, so sorry for spam thread. But if it will be helpfull for someone I used Queue.

Here is how my code looks like after add 2 Queues in CubeMX (recivedData 1024 uint16_t and dataToSend 128 uint8_t):

```
void StartSendTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartSendTask */
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xQueueReceive(dataToSendHandle, sender, 10) ){
          if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem02Handle, ( TickType_t ) 10 ) )
          {
              counter4++;
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
              volatile uint8_t send = CDC_Transmit_FS( sender, (length/8) );
              xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem02Handle );
          }
      }

  }
  /* USER CODE END StartSendTask */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartADCTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the recivedTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/

/* USER CODE END Header_StartADCTask */
void StartADCTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartADCTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem01Handle, ( TickType_t ) 10 ) )
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
          counter1++;
          for( int i = 0 ; i < (length/4) ; i++ ){
              HAL_ADC_Start_DMA( &hadc1, reciver, length);
          }
          if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle ) == pdTRUE )
          {
              xQueueSend(recivedDataHandle, reciver, 10);
              vTaskDelay(1);
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartADCTask */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartPrepareTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the prepareTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/

/* USER CODE END Header_StartPrepareTask */
void StartPrepareTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartPrepareTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if( xQueueReceive(recivedDataHandle, reciver, 10) ){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, !HAL_GPIO_ReadPin( LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin) );
          counter2++;
          if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem01Handle, ( TickType_t ) 10 ) )
          {
              if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem02Handle, ( TickType_t ) 10 ) )
              {
                  volatile uint8_t counter = 0;
                  for( int i = 0; i < (length / (16 * 4)); i ++){
                      for( int j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                          prepared[counter] += reciver[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter];
                          prepared[counter + 1] += reciver[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 1];
                          prepared[counter + 2] += reciver[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 2];
                          prepared[counter + 3] += reciver[i * 16 + j * 4 + counter + 3];
                      }
                      counter += 4;
                  }
                  if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem02Handle ) == pdTRUE )
                  {
                      xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle );
                  }
              } else {
                  xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem01Handle );
              }
          }

          if( xSemaphoreTake( myBinarySem02Handle, ( TickType_t ) 10 ) )
          {
              counter3++;
              for( int i = 0; i < (length / 8); i += 2){
                  sender[0 + i] = prepared[i / 2] >> 8;
                  sender[1 + i] = (prepared[i / 2] << 8) >> 8;
              }
              if( xSemaphoreGive( myBinarySem02Handle ) == pdTRUE )
              {
                  xQueueSend(dataToSendHandle, sender, 10);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartPrepareTask */
}
```